# PHP and Jquery integration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that when a user clicks a button (Jquery), it turns on a function (show images) on the current page and I want that function stay on even when the user clicks a hyperlink and open another page until the user click the same button again to turn it off.

The button exists in every page and could turn on and off the function. I am using Jquery and PHP. Any ideas how to acheive this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into javascript cookies or php sessions.

Comment: Please show code.  This is very vague.  If using jQuery, you don't need the item clicked upon to be an anchor, it can be any element in the DOM.  Even with an anchor, you can `preventDefault` and remain on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

you can set cookies for that, cookie behaves as a global variable there, so u can check if the cookie value is 'on', program should show images, or not, hide all images.